# Showing fragment + viewpager within the same layout; one doesn't show up

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Following is my layout file. It works fine except that when I include both foofragment and foo_pager only one of them show show up (based on which one you add first; in the following case only foofragment is displayed but not foo_pager). What am I missing here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
      android:layout_column="0"
      android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button" />

      <fragment class="view.foofragment"
          android:id="@+id/foo_frag"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
         android:id="@+id/foo_pager"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with layout_weight a little bit and now it is fixed. Thanks for looking into it.